# Excel sumifs formula with condition where first character of criteria_range is letter (a-z)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am facing an challenge where I need to make a SUMIFS formula referencing data in another sheet where I need to sum values if first character of string in one of criteria_range columns is any letter (a-z).

Now, I could bruteforce it with something like this:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"A*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"B*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"C*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"D*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"E*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"F*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"G*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"H*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"I*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"J*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"K*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"L*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"M*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"N*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"O*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"P*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"Q*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"R*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"S*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"T*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"U*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"V*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"W*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"X*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"Y*")+
  SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,"Z*")
```

But I want to believe that there is more elegant solution possible within excel.

Comment: If your column B is just a mixture of numbers, letters and punctuation up to ASCII code 127, then I think you can just use =SUMIF(A:A,">=A",B:B) but I won't offer it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SEQUENCE to return an array of numbers that convert to the letters.  Then sum the results of the arrays:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65))&"*"))
```

[image]

So your formula will be:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!J:J,CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65))&"*"))
```

Comment: I was about to post the exact same. You beat me.

Comment: Amazing and with style. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What aboubt the following formulas

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(ISTEXT(A1:A9)*(B1:B9))
```

Or verify first letter is text if you want to exclude text start with numeric digits.

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(ISTEXT(A1:A9)*(ISERROR(--LEFT(A1:A9,1)))*(B1:B9))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Up Conditionally

- If you don't have MS365, you might consider something like the following.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(Sheet2!B$2:B$11*(Sheet2!C$2:C$11=A2)
    *(SEARCH(LEFT(Sheet2!J$2:J$11,1)," ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")>1),))
```

[image]